# Generating a date relative to another date in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a date in my template context, and I want to display that date plus 7 days in the rendered output.

Something like this (which does not exist):

`{{some_date|plus_days:7}}`

How can I do this in a Django template without writing any Python code?

Comment: Without writing Python code..? Why are you reluctant to write Python?

Comment: It's for custom email templates where the template authors have no access to the Python code (and no JavaScript either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in Django templates as of this writing without writing a custom template tag in Python.

Answer (score 12):

You can create your own [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
import datetime

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def plus_days(value, days):
    return value + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
```

Comment: @djsmith the template authors don't have access to Python code in this solution. You're simply providing an additional template tag that they can use. It can't be done with standard Django tags so you have to build a custom template tag.

Comment: That's the answer I was trying to find. Can this be done? No it cannot.